# -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary saves Memory Usage

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments, jvmti

Recently i encountered a problem in my system that is java used more RAM memory almost near 6 GB of RAM out Of 8GB. So i decided to dig further which part takes more memory with the help of -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary. After enabling this parm i noticed that same kind of program took only 5.5 GB of memory. Could someone clarify me how nativememorytracking helps here?

Comment: Why are you sure it's the effect of NativeMemoryTracking and not some indeterminacy in the application behavior?

Comment: @apangin thanks for your reply, I tried many times. Everytime i observed mentioned behaviour.

Comment: Above mentioned behaviour occurs in both JDK 8 and JDK 11.

Comment: NativeMemoryTracking does not "save" memory pe se. On the contrary, it allocates some extra memory for its own tracking purposes. However, the change in the allocation pattern may affect the algorithm of the allocator, e.g. reduce fragmentation.